# Influx DB issue when inserting new values

Tags: python, insert, grafana, influxdb

I am building a python script for modifying InfluxDB data on an Influx instance that connects NagiosXI with Grafana.

Specifically, I have developed a script that reads some maintenance dates from a csv and then goes and updates the availability performance data inside the InfluxDB.

So far so good.... BUT!

I am calling a bash script from my main python script which shall do the job of inserting the new values onto the influxDB.

The value is changed on the influxDB by the script but, when I open an instance of Grafana, it automatically returns to the previous value the series had!

I am also parsing the query manually from influx CLI and I observe the exact same thing (the value changes for a bit, but when I open a Grafana instance, it returns to the old value).

Is there something on Grafana that pushes back the old value to the Influx Database?

Hope someone can get an answer on this.

BR,
CD

Comment: Grafanna is just a visualization tool.. it pulls data from influx data but doesnt write anything to influx db.. can you give sample of the bash script which inserts into the influx db and may be some more relevant information

Comment: Hello Arun! 

The bash script is the below: 

#!/bin/sh

HOST=$1
TIME=$2

influx -database 'nagflux' -host 'localhost' -port '8086' -execute "INSERT metrics,command=check_chris,host=$HOST,performanceLabel=availability,service=test value=0 $TIME "

BR,
Christos

Comment: Hello Arun!

I just change the workflow of the script. Instead of doing line by line insert, I tried to make a .txt file with the values to be updated and tried the influx -import method.

It seems to be changing again the values to the previous ones.

Comment: I have the default retention policy "autogen" running on these metrics. Maybe this retention policy is modifying the values?

Comment: Found the issue after a lot of searching!! Nagflux on NagiosXI was not configured properly and was always pushing old and new data. After them fix, only new data are pushed on Influx and nothing gets overwritten!